# Hamilton's Lectures on Quaternions or Elements of Quaternions

Tags: vectors, math-history, quaternions

Does anyone know of any detailed study (book, dissertation, thesis, etc.) on Hamilton's Lectures on Quaternions?

I've tried several places but I have not found anything yet.
Thanks any help!

Comment: What languages can you read in?

Comment: It can be in English. But if you do not have English, that's okay, I'll translate.